# Difference between 'same' and 'eq' in EasyMock

Tags: java, easymock

Is there a significant(or even any) difference between 'same' and 'eq' in EasyMock?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`same` checks if both objects are actually the same instance (reference equality). `eq` calls `equals` and therefore checks if both have the same value (value equality).

Keep in mind that the default `equals` implementation uses `==` internally, and therefore `eq` will do the same as `same`if you're using classes that do not have a proper `equals` override.

But still, it's better to state your intent by using `same` for reference equality and `eq` for value equality. It might also help you finding bugs (i.e. finding that you forgot to override `equals`).

Answer (score 18):

same uses `==` and equals uses `.equals()`