# Using object reference equality and not .equals in EasyMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

I'm playing with **EasyMock** and I found something that I don't understand.

I got the subject class `A`(the one being tested) **where `A.equals(Object o)` is `@Override`**.
When i m doing the test below, I got coverage in `A.equals` method :

```
@Test
public void acceptVisitor() {

    subject = EasyMock.createMockBuilder(VariableNode.class).createMock();

    ITermVisitor termVisitor = EasyMock.createMock(ITermVisitor.class);
    termVisitor.visit(subject);

    EasyMock.replay(subject, termVisitor);

    subject.accept(termVisitor);

    EasyMock.verify(subject, termVisitor);

}
```

I don't understand why. So here are my questions :

- Is EasyMock uses `.equals(Object o)` to see if the test call and the expect call use the same arguments ?
- If yes, is there a technique to make it use `==` operator and not `.equals(Object o)` ?

thanks by advance.

Comment: You will probably find your answer here: [Difference between 'same' and 'eq' in EasyMock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654734/difference-between-same-and-eq-in-easymock)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this answer. I already read that topic. I know the difference between `.same(Object o)` and `.equals(Object o)`.
But Is it really `.equals(Object o)` that is used to compare the arguments used in the expect state of the mock and the arguments used in the replay state of the mock ?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, but you could find out by putting a breakpoint in the `equals` method of `A`, running this test in the debugger, and examining the stack when it reaches the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

EasyMock uses the matchers to compare an expectation and an actual invocations. So if you do not specify a matcher and specify `eq`, `equals` will be called on each parameter indeed.

Then, for a mock, EasyMock provides a default implementation for `equals`, which is why `equals` can't be mocked. This default implementation is in fact doing `==`.

In your example, assuming `A` is `subject` which is in fact a `VariableNode`, indeed `equals` will be called on it, again assuming `subject.accept(termVisitor);` is calling `visit`.

BTW, you do not need `subject` to be a mock here. You defined it as a partial mock but without mocking any method so it's basically like a normal class.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Henri for your answer. You gave me the pointer to find what i was needed.

I use an IArgumentMatcher to ensure a comparison of reference between arguments that I give before the EasyMock.replay and the ones after and so don't got the method equals called on my partial mock.

Here is the documentation about this : http://easymock.org/user-guide.html#verification-matchers

And here is the code of my SameArgumentMatcher :

```
import org.easymock.IArgumentMatcher;

public class SameArgumentMatcher implements IArgumentMatcher {

    private Object expected;

    public SameArgumentMatcher(Object expected) {

        this.expected = expected;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object argument) {
        return expected == argument;
    }

    @Override
    public void appendTo(StringBuffer buffer) {
        buffer.append("SameArgumentMatcher(")
                .append(expected.getClass().getName())
                .append("@").append(expected.toString())
                .append(")");
    }

}
```